# Is it possible that a non-empty set has different collections of dense subsets under a (non-trivial) metric and under a (non-trivial) topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be an arbitrary non-empty set. Let $d$ be an arbitrary (non-trivial) metric on $X$. Let $\mathscr{T}$ be an arbitrary (non-trivial) topology on $X$.

Is it possible that $(X,d)$ and $(X,\mathscr{T})$ have different collections of dense subsets (under metric $d$ and under topology $\mathscr{T})$? In other words, is it possible that there exists a subset $S$ of $X$ such that $S$ is either dense in $(X,d)$ or $(X,\mathscr{T})$ but **NOT** both?

Comment: Is it possible for two topologies to define different notions of “dense”? Of course it is. So what makes you think that you cannot do it by forcing one topology to be derived from a metric?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Let $X = \{0,1\} \cup (2,3)$ with the metric inherited from the usual metric for the reals.  The metric for $X$ is not trivial.
Give $X$ the topology with the open sets of all the open sets of $(2,3)$ as a subspace of the reals and the open set $\{0,1\}$.  The topology is not trivial.
$D=\{0\} \cup (2,3)$ is a dense subset of the topological space but not of the metric space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $X=\mathbb R$ and let $\mathscr T$ be the usual topology on $\mathscr R$.
Define a bijection $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as follows:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\ \ \ x\ \text{ if }\ x\in\mathbb Q,\\
-x\ \text{ if }\ x\notin\mathbb Q.
\end{cases}$$
Define the metric $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$.

The set $S=(0,\infty)$ of all positive real numbers is dense in $(X,d)$ but not in $(X,\mathscr T)$.